# A calc 2 question on integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the integral $$\int \frac 5{90-2t} dt$$. 
I thought that's $5ln(90-2t)$. I thought as long as the $t$ is first degree the integral is $ln(denominator)$. Could someone just remind of the rule for this integral? I know I could use a u-substitution method but I want to know the clear rule for integrating when the variable is on the bottom.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}5\log(90 - 2t) = -\frac{10}{90-2t}$. Is this your integrand?

Comment: sorry, when I say "I thought that's ...", I meant I think the answer is. Does that clear things up?

Comment: You essentially answered your own question when you said "I know I could use a u-substitution method..." This is technically that clear rule

Comment: Yes, thank you. I do realize that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is

$$\int \dfrac {du}{u} = \ln |u| + C$$

If you let $u = 90-2t$ on the bottom, then $du = -2 dt$, which is not on the top, so you cannot apply to rule. You must manipulate the top to be $-2 dt$.

To do that, multiply the integral by a convenient form of $1$:

$$\int \frac 5{90-2t} dt= \dfrac {5}{-2}\cdot \dfrac {-2}{5} \int \frac 5{90-2t} dt = \dfrac {5}{-2} \int \frac {-2dt}{90-2t} =\dfrac {5}{-2} \ln |90-2t|+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember the chain rule!
5$\int \frac{1}{u} du = \frac{5}{u’}ln(|u|)$

Comment: Could you explain how this is the chain rule? I am interested to know and cannot see it at the moment.

Comment: @Kovs95 Applying the chain rule here is just another way of using the formula in my answer. We know $\dfrac {d}{dx} \ln x = \dfrac 1x$, so by the chain rule $\dfrac {d}{dx} \ln (u(x)) = \dfrac {u'(x)}{u(x)}$

Comment: Thanks for your response. So the $\frac 1{u'}$ in his answer is the $\frac d{dx}$ in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac 5{90-2t} dt$$

$$ u=90-2t$$
$$du = -2dt$$
$$\int \frac 5{90-2t} dt = \int \frac {-5}{2} \frac {-2}{90-2t} dt= \frac {-5}{2}  \int \frac {du}{u}= $$

$$\frac {-5}{2} ln|u|+C=$$

$$\frac {-5}{2} ln|90-2t|+C=$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method:

$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=ln(f(x))+C$ where $C$ is integral constant.

According to your problem:

$\int\frac{5}{90-2t}dt=\int-\frac{5}{2}*\frac{-2}{90-2t}dt=-\frac{5}{2}ln(90-2t)+C$, $C$ is the constant of integration.